# talend performance - using tMap between tOracleInput and tOutputfFile but with no transformation logic

Tags: talend

My flow is:

```
tOracleInput -> tMap -> tOutputFile
```

Currently, I put a tMap in between incase I will be needing to do some transformation of the fields in the future.  Currently, there is no logic for the fields, it is just a pass-through component.  I wonder if this have an impact on performance or large datasets?  Should I remove it completely since it is not being used for transformation or is it just okay to retain it as it is?

Thank you to anyone who can enlighten me on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ETL components, usually the whole dataset is being downloaded, then processed on the machine the job runs on and reuploaded to the designated server. This uses a lot of ressources.

If the dataset lies in the same database, you might want to check out the ELT components which transfer the processing into the database. You are still able to do some processing.

Comment: can you expound more on "you might want to check out the ELT components which transfer the processing into the database"?

Comment: The documentation page has changes, so those are the names of the components I thought of: tELTOracleInput, tELTOracleMap, tELTOracleOutput. Since your output is a file, this option seems not viable.